# Reproduce Eclipse JAR export with javac on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jar

I need to be able to reproduce the following Eclipse process:

1. Export
2. Runnable JAR file with option "Extract required libraries into generated JAR"

This results in a JAR that includes all the referenced libraries and they have been compiled.

However, when I use this command on Linux:

```
javac -cp lib/lib1.jar:lib/lib2.jar -d newJAR src/Main.java
```

I get a JAR that includes just the class files of my own code.

I need to find a command that could produce the same output as with Eclipse, on the Linux command-line.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on tools like `Maven` and `Ant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for here is non-trivial. You want to package all dependencies into the JAR and also have the class path set so that you can run a class from the new JAR.

Two plugins I have used in the past to do this are maven-assembly-plugin and oneJar plugin.